# Intellij is not deploying properly on tomcat

Tags: debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea

i am trying to debug my java server application with intelliJ and tomcat, but i can not manage to start it successfully. I have here the configuration for you, [Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKW2i.png) and [Deployement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ql90S.png). I did not touch the rest of the settings. 
If i go to the tomcat manager, i can see the project, but can not access it. If i deploy the war file over the manager, suddenly i can debug my project...
Did i miss something in my settings?

Comment: Too little information. Add information about what you do and what exactly the problem.

Comment: See this tutorial: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-ee-application.html

Comment: its a simple server which reveives REST request, only GET and PULL. It has a database with songs in it and the songs can be read or edited by the request. 
When i start the project with tomcat on intellij i only get HTTP 404. Something in the settings are not working correctly, because if i simply deploy it manually it works.